# How to add paraent in Blog post URL in wordpress

Tags: posts, permalinks, urls, blog-page

I have a post in WordPress with having URL like
https://digital.co/testpost

I want to change the URL to something like
https://digital.co/blogs/testpost

How can I do that in a simple WordPress blog post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this in your WordPress settings.

Go to your Permalinks settings `(WP Admin → Settings → Permalinks)` and select ‘Custom Structure’. It should display your current structure in the text box next to it. Now, add `/blogs` in front of what is in the text box. And then Save.

See screenshot for reference
[image]